# Why does my Fish Game score overlay itself as it updates?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

The game works by a fish eating smaller fish and slowly growing bigger. The score is supposed to update each time the fish eats another fish. The score will update to one right when you eat a fish, but it won't update to a 2 until you eat a bunch of fish(it varies), and then the 2 shows up over the 1.

[image: The score not updating properly]

**Read at your own risk:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title> Fish Game! </title>
    <script src="https://simplycodingcourses.com/files/simplyjs/simply.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function start(){
             sjs.open("target", 800, 500);

             var background = new sjs.Image("Images/background.png");
             background.setSize(sjs.getWidth(), sjs.getHeight());

             //Player Properties below here
             var player = new sjs.Image("Images/fish_left.png");
             player.type = "player";
             player.setSize(100,50);
             player.friction = .1;
             player.accel = .6;

             sjs.keyDown(RIGHT_KEY, function(){
                 player.setImage("Images/fish_right.png");
                 player.pushRight();
             });

             sjs.keyDown(LEFT_KEY, function(){
                 player.setImage("Images/fish_left.png");
                 player.pushLeft();
             });

             sjs.keyDown(UP_KEY, function(){
                 player.pushUp();
             });

             sjs.keyDown(DOWN_KEY, function(){
                 player.pushDown();
             });


         //Powerup

         setInterval(function(){
             var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 783);
             var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 470);
             var powerUp = new 
             sjs.Image("Images/crumbs.png");
             powerUp.type = "powerUp";
             powerUp.setGravity();
             powerUp.setSize(17,30);
             powerUp.noBounds = true;
             powerUp.moveTo(x, y);
             powerUp.friction = 0.2;
         }, 5000);

         sjs.onHit("powerUp", "bottom_screen", function(x,y){
             x.destroy();
         });

         sjs.onHit("player","powerUp", function(x,y){
             x.grow(60,30);
             setTimeout(function(){
                 x.grow(-60,-30)
             }, 5000);
             y.destroy();
         });

         //Enemies
         setInterval(function(){
             var speed = Math.round(1 + Math.random()*10);
             if(Math.random() > 0.5){
                 var enemy = new sjs.Image("Images/fish2_right.png");
                 enemy.type = "enemy";
                 enemy.setSize(100,50);
                 enemy.noBounds = true;
                 enemy.friction = 0;
                 enemy.pushRight(speed);
                 enemy.scaleSize(.5 + Math.random() *1.2);
                 enemy.moveTo(-enemy.getWidth(), Math.random()*(enemy.getClamp().y));
             } else{
                 var enemy = new sjs.Image("Images/fish2_left.png");
                 enemy.type = "enemy";
                 enemy.setSize(100,50);
                 enemy.noBounds = true
                 enemy.friction = 0;
                 enemy.pushLeft(speed);
                 enemy.scaleSize(.5 + Math.random() * 1.2);
                 enemy.moveTo(sjs.getWidth(), Math.random()*(enemy.getClamp().y));
             }
             sjs.left_screen.offset(-500);
             sjs.right_screen.offset(500);

             sjs.onHit("enemy",["right_screen","left_screen"],function(x,y){
                 x.destroy();
             });

             //Score 
             var score = 0;
             var score_txt = new sjs.Text("Score: ", 21, "orange");

             sjs.onHit("player","enemy",function(x,y){
                 if(x.getWidth() > y.getWidth() && x.getHeight() > y.getHeight()) {
                     score = score + 1;
                     score_txt.setText("Score: " + score);
                     localStorage.setItem("score", score);
                     x.grow(10,5);
                     if(score >= 20){
                         window.location = "win.html";
                     }
                 } else {
                    //x.destroy();
                    //window.location = "gameover.html";
                    console.log("Normally I would die but that got annoying so for now you will just get me AAAAA");
                 }

                 y.destroy();
             });

         },1000);

         } //end start
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="start()">
    <h1>Fish Dominance</h1>

    <div id="target" style="margin:auto;background:white;"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I know nothing about that library `Simply.js` but it looks from the picture that you are drawing on the same text, and by looking at your code, I see the object `score_txt = new sjs.Text("Score: ", 21, "orange");` that's being created every 1 second, so you should just create it once inside the `start` function at the beginning and the same goes for the `score` variable to keep track of the score for example

```
function start(){
  var score = 0;
  var score_txt = new sjs.Text("Score: ", 21, "orange");
  // the rest of your code
}
```